# Why is Overpass-turbo map empty if there is data?

Tags: data, cartography, overpass-api

[image]

I started with overpass and am using the overpass-turbo.eu site. How comes that the map is empty when there is data? In particular, the park marked in blue shows up in the xml file (with the tag leisure="park") but its not marked on the map.

I would like to query for parks in the close range of the user.

**SOLUTION:**

```
way[leisure="park"](around:4500,47.0546694,15.4570067); out geom;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace `out;` by `out geom;` to also include the way's nodes in your response.

NB: Next time, please provide a link to your query by pressing the "Share" button in overpass turbo. A screenshot is really not that useful for others to reproduce your issue.